# OpenCV Python and a webcam

Tags: python, linux, opencv, webcam, beagleboard

I'm working with [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) on a [BeagleBoard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard) with [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) and OpenCV 1.1 interfaced via [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29). I'm trying to set something up to capture a feed from a UVC compatible webcam (Logitech C250). I have tested the webcam with luvcview, and it works, but only if I set the input format to YUV. If I run it in 'normal' mode I am getting back [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) frames and something - somewhere is not happy!

I'm trying to connect with the webcam in OpenCV as I want to get the image back from the webcam and run some analysis on it. As I have a limited device this seems to be the most efficient way of doing it - however I need to instruct the capturing system to capture in YUV and not JPEG. Is there a way of doing this (for example luvcview allow me to enter luvcview -f YUVY)?

Comment: By 'limited device' do you mean limited processing power on the host computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've cracked this partly.  If you compile OpenCV with the flag WITH_JPEG=OFF then the camera will not try to use MJPEG.